# How do you intergrate jquery library modules into your javascript framework using require js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I cloned the jquery library and tried to integrate it with my own JavaScript library without much success.

I do not need all the jquery functionality ,hence the need to only load the relevant jquery modules with the functionality i want.I have been able to load the core module (core.js) and have successfully utilized some of the functionality, however the functionality provided is limited in that i am unable to do chaining or even do simple stuff such as html element selection.Interestingly id selectors work perfectly fine, but element creation is not working.

Example code of what is working and not working.

```
define([
"../jquery/src/core",
"../jquery/src/selector",
],
function( 
jqcore,
jqselector
){
//this works fine
var div_element = jqcore("#mydiv");

//This does not work ,i want to understand why this is not working
var body_element = jqcore("body");

//I would like to understand why i am not able to do this or what i should do for the   code below to work
jqcore("p").append("<b>Appended text</b>");

})
```

I am using sizzle selector which i belive is being loaded corrently but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you included the sizzle selector? (you claim you load it but I don't see it implemented in the code?)

See documentation
https://github.com/jquery/jquery (chapter modules)

I believe this paragraph describes the problem you are having:

sizzle: The Sizzle selector engine. When this module is excluded, it is replaced by a rudimentary selector engine based on the browser's querySelectorAll method that does not support jQuery selector extensions or enhanced semantics. See the selector-native.js file for details.

That would explain the basic selector support.

Comment: From my understanding the sizzle module is loaded automatically by the selector.js module. I have included selector.js module in the code above. I concluded that sizzle is being loaded from studying the code found in selector.js module.

Comment: I see what you mean. I looked in the source, it seems to be something ex-library ("../bower_components/sizzle/dist/sizzle"). You sure it is found and loaded? alternatively, you could try selector-native, although it is less feature-rich.